# Cache Object and Commit on Page Load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What we want to do is save an entire control into Cache and recommit the properties on page load, including data items. But we'd like the controls to exist already in the page.

Is this possible?

```
<html>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rptListOfSubscribers">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Name")%><br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
</html>
```

VB:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        If Cache("MyRepeater") Is Nothing Then
            Dim rpt As Repeater = InitaliseRepeater()
        Cache.Insert("MyRepeater"), rpt, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(720), Tim

eSpan.Zero)
        End If

        rptListOfSubscribers = Cache("MyRepeater")

End Sub

    Function InitaliseRepeater() As Repeater

        Dim rpt As New Repeater
        rpt.DataSource = x
        rpt.DataBind()

    Return rpt
End Function
```

Excuse the short-hand code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible the cache will take any object including a webcontrol. However probably best to do it earlier than Page_Load -Page_init perhaps.

Also I am curious as to your reasons behind doing this .. It seems like an awful solution. Also when you add the control to the page again when the viewstate page cycle methods run it will potentially change the control instance you have...

Can you describe the problem you are trying to solve with the cached web control?

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it doesn't work in Page_Load or Page_Init or even Page_PreInit.

If you add the control to a placeholder: ph.Controls.Add(Cache("MyRepeater")) it works! But then you don't have control of <ItemTemplate>.

The ONLY context we'd use this is in a basic list that wouldn't have any interactivity and wouldn't change often. It might just be a nav, blog list or banner images in a website. We are exploring options to Cache and save on performance/load time. Of course we can commit a List to Cache but the thought is to create an abstract function that could be used for any control.